# Python codigo de descuento

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

El programa debe pedir una categoría y un monto hasta recibir la palabra "cancelar" en lugar de una categoría.

1. Cuando se ingrese la palabra "cancelar" en lugar de una categoría, el programa debe mostrar "Compra cerrada" y apagarse.
2. Tras recibir el costo de los bienes, el programa debe, dependiendo de la categoría, aplicar cierto descuento y mostrar el monto que se debe pagar en la pantalla. Luego, debe solicitar nuevamente una categoría.
3. Si no hay descuentos para la categoría, el programa debe mostrar el monto a pagar sin aplicar descuentos.

Descuentos disponibles:
Productos lácteos - 10% de descuento.
Productos horneados - 30% de descuento.

Escribe un programa así. En la imagen se muestra un posible resultado del programa.
**OTRA forma de escribir el codigo de forma corta y eficiente? Sin BREAK, muchas gracias por sus ideas de planteamiento**

```
while True:
    a= input('Introduce la categoría')
    if (a=="cancelar"):
        print("Compra cerrada")
        break
    else:
        b= float(input('Introduce el precio del producto'))
        descuento=0
        if (a == "Productos lácteos"):
            descuento=0.10
        elif (a == "Productos horneados"):
            descuento=0.30
        else:
            descuento = 0
        print('Descuento de ',descuento*100,'%.',' Por pagar: ', (b-(b*descuento)))
```

Comment: Si fueran más descuentos, deberías usar un diccionario en lugar de `if-else`. El diccionario tiene por llave la categoría y por valor el descuento.

Comment: Como se realizaría de esa forma?

Comment: `{"productos lacteos":0.1, "productos horneados":0.3}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas he puesto como han comentado en un diccionario agregandole Otros productos con 0% y visionado con un print como menú a elegir, luego sólo mostramos resultados, de esta manera puedes añadir mas categorias en el diccionario y sigue funcionando.

```
categorias={'Productos lacteos':10, 'Productos horneados':30, 'Otros 
productos':0}
print(categorias['Productos lacteos'])    
while True:
    print('''
    Productos lacteos
    Productos horneados
    Otros productos
    Cancelar
    ''') 
    a= input('Introduce la categoría: ')
    if a.capitalize()=="Cancelar":
      print("Compra cerrada")
      break
    else:
      b= float(input('Introduce el precio del producto: '))
      print('Descuento de {}%.  Por pagar:  {} '.format(categorias[a.capitalize()]/100, (b-(b*categorias[a.capitalize()]/100))))
```